# Term for deformation due to gravity

Tags: planetary-science, terminology

In this video,

If you look closely, you can see the smaller planet deforming before the actual collision. I think I remember a term existed for this. I think it is similar to Spaghettification, but for just normal planets and similar objects. Maybe it's called 'X distance,' where X is some word I cannot remember or could be something else.

Comment: Please read our [about] page to understand how the site works. It will help you understand why a) saying thanks in comments is not helpful and will be deleted, b) the voting buttons and the checkmark to accept posts are the only useful ways to show your approval or disapproval for posts, and c) continuing to deliberately flout rules does end up in suspensions

Comment: @RoryAlsop go ahead and suspend me then. its **my choice** what posts I accept or dont accept, not yours. sadly many people on this site seem to lack understanding that accepting a post actually discourages many from adding further posts. so a thanks comment is actually more effective in that it notifies a "correct" answer without discouraging more answers. this is important in the early days of a question being asked. so no as I said before I wont be bullied into accepting or commenting in certain ways.

Comment: If you do not wish to accept an answer, that's fine. But your behaviour in continually spamming your unwelcome comments is not acceptable. Especially when asked not to by the person whose post you are commenting on.

Answer (score 23):

The generic term is tidal deformation. At a distance of ~385000 km, the Moon subtly distorts the shape of the Earth. Those distortions are readily visible in the Earth's oceanic tides, and not quite as readily visible in the Earth's solid body tides (but still quite observable with good instrumentation). The Sun also causes tides on the Earth, about half as strong as those caused by the Moon.

These tidal distortions can in some cases rip bodies apart. A nice example was comet Shoemaker–Levy 9, which was captured by Jupiter, then later ripped apart  into at least 21 pieces, which then collided with Jupiter in a well observed series of events. The comet eventually fell well within Jupiter's Roche limit, thereby causing it to be torn into pieces. Even more extreme cases involve relativistic as well as Newtonian distortions. As noted in the question, this extreme form of tidal distortions results in spaghettification.

The Roche limit is an approximation of the distance to a strong gravitational source at which a smaller body might be torn apart by gravity. If a body is composed of small particles that are bound together by self gravitation only, tidal distortions might well rip the body apart if it gets too close to a strong gravitational source.

Comets are loosely connected chunks of smaller pieces of ice and minerals that are collectively bound together mostly by gravity. The smaller pieces of comet Shoemaker–Levy 9 were bound chemically as well as gravitationally; this is why I called the Roche limit an approximation. The 21 (or more) smaller pieces remained intact until they collided with Jupiter's atmosphere.

Answer (score 19):

Could you be thinking of the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit)?  From the link:

> In celestial mechanics, the Roche limit, also called Roche radius, is the distance from a celestial body within which a second celestial body, held together only by its own force of gravity, will disintegrate because the first body's tidal forces exceed the second body's self-gravitation.[1] Inside the Roche limit, orbiting material disperses and forms rings, whereas outside the limit, material tends to coalesce.

Comment: @user22859957 there's a checkmark button for accepting answers

Comment: Hi @user22859957 - please click on the checkmark button next to the post that best answers you - that moves it to the top and ensures future visitors will see the correct answer first.

Comment: The Roche limit is a radius, not a concept like "deformation due to gravity". This answer is semantically off. Also it's just a copypaste.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape OP has confirmed twice, in comments since deleted, it was what they were trying to think of.  I don't need to write a short paper on the definition of the Roche Limit to help someone remember a word.

Comment: @user22859957 please don't keep posting the comment, at the very least so you don't keep sending it to my inbox (which is where comments on my answer end up).  I'm not deleting your comments, I don't particularly agree with the mods doing it, but all I've tried to do is help.